# Simple WCF service - all requests returning empty?

Tags: c#, wcf

Im currently failing at testing a simple WCF service with the `WebGet` attribute applied, as per the tutorial at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178.aspx

Ive created a blank ASP.NET web application project, ive then added a WCF service called 'test', which creates `test.svc` and `Itest.svc`.

I've then added the method 'hello':

```
public class test : Itest
{
    public string hello(string s){return "hello " + s;}
}
```

which implements the interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface Itest
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    string hello(string s);
}
```

However, any requests (HTTP GETs) to `http://localhost/test.svc/hello?s=hi` return an empty page.
As a matter of fact, any request under that url return a blank page (i.e. `http://localhost/test.svc/abcdefg`)

Am I missing something fundamental?

Edit: web.config completely standard apart from visual studio generated:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Itest" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/test.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Itest" contract="ServiceReference1.Itest"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_Itest" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Using the [WebGet] attribute, I dont want to use it with a service reference.
Having said that, it does work when testing with wcftestclient.exe

Comment: Ive tested other browsers and made the webrequest programatically... still get an empty response.

Comment: Try updating the `WebGet` to something like `[WebGet(UriTemplate = "foo", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]`

Comment: changed UriTemplate to above, did nothing, nor did changing web.config's binding="webHttpBinding"

Answer (score 2):

You should use webHttpBinding instead to basicHttpBinding 
Here's part of the answer from here: [testing wcf service in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578084/testing-wcf-service-in-browser/2578155#2578155)

> It depends on what type of WCF service you have:
>
> if you're using a WCF REST service (webHttpBinding), then you should be able to just navigate to the service address, e.g. http://yourserver/somedir/service.svc
>
> if you're using anything else, you have a SOAP service, and you cannot test a SOAP service in a web browser - the browser just doesn't understand and speak SOAP. There's however a WCF Test Client app in your C:\ drive somewhere which you can use for that purpose.

From myself can add that WCFTestCLient is here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe"

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the above section in web.config with the below one:

```
    <system.serviceModel>    
    <services>
      <service name="ServiceReference1.test">
      <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.Itest" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Your server needs to have the services element and not client element in your web.config as shown above. Also to use webGet you need to use webHttpBinding

Answer (score 0):

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Apr/10/WCF-REST-Configuration-for-ASPNET-AJAX-and-plain-REST-Services