# Service Only Works While Debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, powershell, iis

I have created a `WCF` service and am having some trouble testing it once it has been deployed. Here is the PowerShell I am using to test it:

```
$service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri http://localhost:16651/Service.svc
$service.GetList()
```

When debugging the service from `Visual Studio` with `F5`, I can call this script without any issue. `GetList()` returns a long list of telephone numbers.

However, when I host the site on IIS and run the above script, I get an **empty** return value.

---

#### Service Factory

So following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474232/simple-wcf-service-all-requests-returning-empty), I added this attribute to `Service.svc`:

```
Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"
```

However, this resulted in my script returning an error on the first line:

> New-WebServiceProxy : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Which does not make any sense to me, as I am not referencing any empty objects... (this error appears when debugging and when hosting over IIS).

---

#### Web.Config

Next, I tried updated my `web.config` as per the linked question:

```
<services>
  <service name="LyncWebService.Service">
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="LyncWebService.IService" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>   
    <serviceBehaviors>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="web">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

However, now when I try to run my PowerShell script I get this error both during debugging and when hosting on IIS (again on the first line):

> The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.

---

I am totally lost here and have no idea what is going wrong. I suspect it is to do with my config file, as it did seem to work when debugging from VS before I messed with the configuration.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated - and please let me know if I can provide any other information or test anything.

Here is the code that makes up my service currently:

#### Service.svc.cs

```
namespace LyncWebService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        List<string> GetList();
    }
    public class Service : IService
    {
        public List<string> GetList()
        {
            return Ps.GetAssignedNumbers(@"
                Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
                Import-Module Lync
                $(Get-CSUser).LineUri"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

#### Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
        <service name="LyncWebService.Service">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="LyncWebService.IService" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
        </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>   
        <serviceBehaviors>
        </serviceBehaviors>

        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="web">
            <webHttp/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
      <!--<add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>-->
      <add binding="webHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Just a side question - have you considerd using ASP.NET WebAPI instead of WCF?

Comment: @MartinBrandl I have not. The only reason I am using `WCF` is because I read somewhere that this is now recommended over `asmx` (which is what I was using previously). Would you recommend `ASP.NET` over both of these?

Comment: Yes, nowadays I would *always* greate a ligthwight REST API instead of WCF SOAP unless I realy have to use it. Take a look at: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: @MartinBrandl Thanks for the tip! I will take a look now and see how it goes

Comment: Make sure your service is running as administrator.

I had this issue too, if your service is running as an actual service in the task manager make sure that it is using an admin account and not a localuser or else you wont get anything back :)

Comment: @JonathanCoffey That was it! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Jonathan Coffey, I realised that the service was being run by the `LocalSystem` account.

After changing this to my own user account and hosting the original `web.config` on `IIS`, I am now able to retrieve the full list using my PowerShell script.

1. Open IIS
2. Application Pools
3. Right-Click the Application pool
4. Advanced Settings...
5. Process Model -> Identity
6. Custom Account (Don't forget to include the domain for the User Name!)